# Proof that an n-dimensional subspace over $\mathbf{C}$ is closed

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I'm trying to understand this proof in Rudin's Functional Analysis text:

[image]

I don't understand the line about $p$ being contained in the closure of $Y \cap tV \subset f(tB) \subset f(t \overline{B})$. We have that $p$ is in $\overline{Y}$ and $p$ is in $tV$, but why does this imply that $p \in \overline{Y \cap (tV)}$?

Comment: Since $p\in\bar{Y}$, there is a sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ in $Y$ that converges to $p$. Eventually the terms of the sequence all lie in $tV$ since $p\in tV$ and $tV$ is open. Thus $p$ is a limit point of $Y\cap(tV)$.

Comment: So more generally, if $p \in \overline{A}$ and $p \in B$ with $B$ open, then $p \in \overline{A \cap B}$?

Comment: yes that's right